# How can I disable Ivy's SHA1 check of the downloaded .pom files?

Tags: checksum, ivy

My current Ivy configuration fails to resolve because of this error:

```
problem while downloading module descriptor:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.pom:
invalid sha1:
  expected=ad3fda4adc95eb0d061341228cc94845ddb9a6fe
  computed=0ce5d4a03b07c8b00ab60252e5cacdc708a4e6d8
```

How can I disable (or work around) Ivy's check of the SHA1 checksum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could tell your resolver to ignore checksums by setting the property to an empty String.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html

Or you could define it globally by setting the attribute ivy.checksums to "":

From the Documentation (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html#checksum):

> For the moment Ivy supports the md5
>   and sha1 algorithms.
>
> The configuration of using md5 and/or
>   sha1 can be done globally or by
>   dependency resolver. Globally, use the
>   ivy.checksums variable to list the
>   check to be done (only md5 and sha1
>   are supported). On each resolver you
>   can use the checksums attribute to
>   override the global setting.
>
> The setting is a comma separated list
>   of checksum algorithms to use. During
>   checking (at download time), the first
>   checksum found is checked, and that's
>   all. This means that if you have a
>   "sha1, md5" setting, then if ivy finds
>   a sha1 file, it will compare the
>   downloaded file sha1 against this
>   sha1, and if the comparison is ok, it
>   will assume the file is ok. If no sha1
>   file is found, it will look for an md5
>   file. If none is found no checking is
>   done. During publish, all listed
>   checksum algorithms are computed and
>   uploaded.
>
> By default checksum algorithms are
>   "sha1, md5".
>
> If you want to change this default,
>   you can set the variable
>   ivy.checksums. Hence, to disable
>   checksum validation you just have to
>   set ivy.checksums to "".

Comment: If using Play Framework (2.3) with sbt (in your build.sbt): checksums := Seq("")

Answer (score 0):

I just found this about the checksum issue:
[Corrupt checksum in Maven Central](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-46)